OpenCV-Python Bindings, vector<>, Matx<> conversion
I am following this to create openCV-python bindings to my code as custom module that can be used as a shared library.
With simpler structs and classes it runs without issues and i am able to import and work with them in python, however when i try converting classes that has arg types with vector<> or cv::Matx<> it fails
struct CV_EXPORTS_W_SIMPLE foo{ 
   CV_WRAP foo(int param, std::vector<someparameter> someparamter)   
       {someparameter =_someparameter}
   }

it fails or reads the python bindings as vector_someparameter
I have tried CV_EXPORTS_W, it also fails if i declare the said parameter as CV_PROP_RW to expose it to python.
